Problem integrating huawei_ads in Flutter
Trying to integrate huawei_ads in Flutter but received the following error when buidling the app:
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/huawei_ads.dart:26:6: Error: Error when reading '/src/adslite/bidding_param.dart': No such file or directory
part '/src/adslite/bidding_param.dart';
     ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/huawei_ads.dart:26:6: Error: Can't use '/src/adslite/bidding_param.dart' as a part, because it has no 'part of' declaration.
part '/src/adslite/bidding_param.dart';
     ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/ad_param.dart:67:45: Error: Type 'BiddingParam' not found.
  AdParam addBiddingParamMap(String slotId, BiddingParam biddingParam) {
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/ad_param.dart:75:42: Error: Type 'BiddingParam' not found.
  AdParam setBiddingParamMap(Map<String, BiddingParam> biddingParamMap) {
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/request_options.dart:70:52: Error: Type 'BiddingParam' not found.
  RequestOptions addBiddingParamMap(String slotId, BiddingParam param) {
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/request_options.dart:75:49: Error: Type 'BiddingParam' not found.
  RequestOptions setBiddingParamMap(Map<String, BiddingParam> biddingParamMap) {
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/ad_param.dart:67:45: Error: 'BiddingParam' isn't a type.
  AdParam addBiddingParamMap(String slotId, BiddingParam biddingParam) {
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/ad_param.dart:75:42: Error: 'BiddingParam' isn't a type.
  AdParam setBiddingParamMap(Map<String, BiddingParam> biddingParamMap) {
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/ad_param.dart:79:29: Error: The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toJson'.
      paramMap[key] = value.toJson();
                            ^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/request_options.dart:70:52: Error: 'BiddingParam' isn't a type.
  RequestOptions addBiddingParamMap(String slotId, BiddingParam param) {
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/request_options.dart:75:49: Error: 'BiddingParam' isn't a type.
  RequestOptions setBiddingParamMap(Map<String, BiddingParam> biddingParamMap) {
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/huawei_ads-13.4.72+300/lib/src/adslite/request_options.dart:79:29: Error: The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toJson'.
      paramMap[key] = value.toJson();
                            ^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1297

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have already mentioned the problem "received the error when building the app"
